# How to set QueryString parameter for test in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a file - utils.js, which includes the function:

```
export const getLocationPage = () => {
  const locationPage = QueryString.parse(location.search).page;
  return locationPage ? locationPage : "undefined";
};
```

utils.js is not a component, but a simple .js file whhich other components use.

How can I test the logic of this function? I mean, how can I set the value of the queryString in the test?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can set value for QueryString:

```
// Testing Claim Details component 
describe('<ClaimDetails />', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(
     // Add initail props and values
      <ClaimDetails
        loading={false}
        locationPage={"some string"}
      />
    )
  })

  it('ClaimDetails: If Claim is null component should not be rendered', () => {
 // *** Here you can setProps value of Query string in SetProps{}
    wrapper.setProps({
      locationPage: "Some String Value",
    })
    expect(wrapper.html()).toBeNull()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikola Trajkovic ! is ClaimDetails the name of the class that has the function you test?
Because I don't have what to shallow because it's not an exported class, what I have is just a file with some functions, how can I shallow it?